# Django: put request.FILES in request.SESSION

Tags: python, django, django-sessions, django-file-upload

I'm trying to put the request.session fields in my request.session for use it later. But when I simply write:

```
request.session['fileInfo'] = request.FILES
```

I always get this error:

```
Pickilng error: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I've resolved in other way. Anyway, I needed this for keep the file for an other view. :)

ps. Had you edited my question? Why? :)

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I used the localStorage, a feature of broswsers and html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is sessions are transformed to strings using a standard module called `pickle`. `pickle` must be able to transform all objects in the session `dict`.

The `request.FILES` object is not `pickle-able`.

Comment: Your final point is not really true, the session data itself isn't stored in the cookie, just the ID. The data is in the session storage backend, which is usually the database.

Comment: Right you are. I removed the offending sentence